# How to disable the "Autocomplete for cell values" on Excel using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubyxl

While exporting the EXCEL file using Ruby or Rails, I faced something that needs to be disabled the Autocomplate for cell values.
Is there any solution for it?

```
require 'rubyXL'

workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet

no_autofill_style = workbook.styles.add(autoComplete: 'off')

worksheet.sheet_data.rows.each do |row|
  row.cells.each do |cell|
    cell.styleIndex = no_autofill_style 
  end
end
```

I have tried like this but failed to add styles into workbook

Comment: If you do the formatting in Excel, and then load this into Ruby, what style value does Ruby it print?